# Postgresql Generate regular timestamp series

Tags: r, postgresql-8.4

I am running pass-through queries using postgresql(8.4.2) from R using PivotalR package. I need to generate a series of timestamp values incremented by seconds and merge the series to each value of a column. Something like

```
col a   series
  a     2015-01-24 09:30:01
  a     2015-01-24 09:30:02
  b     2015-01-24 09:30:01
  b     2015-01-24 09:30:02
```

What are the ways to do this? I am not able use generate_series() because, i think the version doesn't support the function.

Comment: What's wrong with `seq.POSIXt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ BondedDust Thanks. I used `seq(ISOdate(<year,month,day,h,m,s>),by=1,length.out=n)`. Then exported it to the database as a data frame and did a join on the dates. Does the trick.